# How to locate the certain value of an item using xpath?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I've written a script in `python` in combination with `lxml` library using `xpath` to parse the value of a certain apartment from a webpage. The name of that aparment visible in that site is `Eden Tolly Cascades` and the value of it is `15.92 to 36.28 Lac`. How can i parse the value of it mentioning that apartment name within my xpath?

I've tried like below and it is working without any issues. However, ain't there any cleaner approach to achieve the same?

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

url = "https://www.99acres.com/ppc-2515-residential-apartment-mailer"

res = requests.get(url)
tree = fromstring(res.text)
item = tree.xpath("//h1[contains(.,'Eden Tolly')]/../../../following::div//span/strong/text()")[0]
print(item)
```

This is one such container:

```
<div class="pro-text">
    <div class="product-text-box">
        <div class="product-heading">
            <span><img src="https://newprojects.99acres.com/projects/eden_group/eden_tolly_cascades/ln9rkpsb.jpg">
                <h1 class="font-size15">Eden Tolly Cascades<p>Kabardanga</p></h1>
            </span> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-text-box">
    <ul class="product-lrg-box">
        <li> <span><strong><span class="rupee-font">₹ &nbsp;</span>15.92 to 36.28 Lac</strong></span></li>
        <li><strong>549-1251 SQFT</strong></li>

        <li><strong>1-3 BHK</strong></li>
        <li style="width:20% !important;"><strong>New Launch</strong></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs" class="tab-link tabs-menu tabs-menu-new">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#304355broch">e-Brochure</a></li>
            <li><a href="#304355amn">Amenities</a></li>
            <!--  <li style="width:20% !important;"><a href="#304355floor">Floor Plan</a></li>-->
            <li style="width:20% !important;"><a href="#304355dir">Directions</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="enquire-new-bt" id="304355-583061,151100-enquire-new-bt" data-val="3"> <a href="javascript:void(0)">I am Interested</a> </span> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share HTML code sample for the same as it seem that target URL is unreachable (at least for me)?

Comment: Sure sir. I didn't notice you responded. I was terribly expecting your presence. Gonna update with the relevant html.

Comment: @sir Andesson, few months back you provided me with a uniquely awesome `xpath` created to parse titles from `https://finance.yahoo.com/` and the expression was `"//a[u[@class='StretchedBox']]/text()"`. However, I was trying to follow the pattern to build the same here but could not succeed.

Comment: Hmm... You can try this one `//div[contains(.//h1, 'Eden Tolly')]/following-sibling::div//span/strong/text()`, but I'm not sure that it's really *"clearer"*... Let me know which part of XPath expression you want to simplify

Comment: Please post it as an answer @sir Andersson. This is exactly the expression I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below XPath

```
//div[contains(.//h1, 'Eden Tolly')]/following-sibling::div//span/strong/text()
```

Comment: One thing to know sir: they both work identically `following-sibling` and `following` in this case. Can you give me a clue why?

Comment: `following` matches elements on different DOM levels (nodes with different/same parent) while `following-sibling` on the same level only (nodes with the same direct parent). Simply put, `following-sibling` is just more precise version of `following`